# What is a canonical way to produce a segmentation fault in C#?

Tags: c#, segmentation-fault

I am interested in the shortest, neatest piece of C# code around that will reliably produce a segfault - ideally without directly calling any unmanaged code.

Comment: Not likely to happen. Segfault in managed code would mean a bug in the JIT / runtime and in some situations a vulnerability. If it's possible, it's going to be fixed soon-ish.

Comment: A complete compilable answer to this should only be about a dozen lines.

Comment: @viraptor: No, the runtime may handle the segmentation fault (on Windows the term is "access violation") and throw a NullPointerException, but that's not the same as never having a segmentation fault.  All you need is unverifiable code (in C#, that means compiling `/unsafe`)

Comment: If you're just looking for an `AccessViolationException`, you don't need unsafe code, just one line of interop: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.Zero);`

Comment: @ben: If you need a `NullPointerException` / `AccessViolationException`, you can throw it yourself. I understood the question as "how to produce a segfault that is not handled as an exception". I don't see a reason to do this otherwise... but it seems that's what Tom was after.

Comment: @viraptor: "segfault that is not handled as an exception" makes no sense whatsoever.  Access violations are CPU exceptions, and the ones not processed internally by Windows cause a "structured exception" to be thrown.

Comment: @Ben: Of course it will always be an exception for the system - but there's a possibility that the .NET runtime's handler also fails, in which case the whole VM environment crashes instead of producing an exception which can be handled int he code. <- this is what I meant.

Comment: @viraptor: That too can be accomplished in a perfectly bugfree CLR implementation as long as full control permission is had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're after is somewhat unclear but I suppose this is as good as any answer so far, and it is about as minimal as you can get.

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.Zero);`

Answer (score 4):

Michael's answer wasn't working for me, perhaps that case is caught now. Marshal.ReadInt32() just gives me a "SystemError: Attempted to read or write protected memory." with .NET 4.5 on Windows for various passed values. I used the following however which segfaults for me both on Windows and under mono 4.0.4.1:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void UNMANAGED_CALLBACK();

    public void Crash()
    {
        var crash = (UNMANAGED_CALLBACK)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((IntPtr) 123, typeof(UNMANAGED_CALLBACK));
        crash();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a proper in "Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code." with stack trace and core dump in Mono 5.2.0.215.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments above, there's no such thing as a segfault in Windows, and you didn't say anything about mono on Linux. So I'm going to assume you actually meant an access violation.

Here's a way to get one:

```
unsafe {
    int* a = (int*) -4;
    *a = 0;
}
```

(Must be compiled with the `/unsafe` option.)

My first try used 0 as the address, but that turned out to throw a plain old NullReferenceException, which you can get without unsafe code. But the negative address gets an AccessViolationException on my Vista x64 box.

Comment: Interestingly this results in `NullReferenceException` on Mono 1.9.1 running under Linux, so I guess it's architecture-dependent (or Mono gets it wrong!).

Comment: Thanks.  As far as terminology is concerned, I'm happy with calling an "access violation" a segfault - always have been.

Answer (score -1):

Compile with `csc` with the `/unsafe` option:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int *p = null;
            *p = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually throws a NullReferenceException, which is easy enough to get with plain old .NET. I'm assuming OP is after something more like an AccessViolationException.

Comment: Under the covers an access violation (native exception code 0xC0000005) results from the null pointer dereference which is then trapped by the CLR and translated into an instance of `System.NullReferenceException`.