# Post-mortem debugging of a Mono AOT-compiled program

Tags: linux, mono, gdb

I have a large program, written in C# and running on Linux systems using Mono, that occasionally crashes and causes the `mono.bin` process to dump core.

I ran `gdb` on some of the core dump files, but it wasn't very useful because the backtraces don't have the names of the C# functions in them.  According to [this discussion I found](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Post-mortem-debugging-td4238349.html):

> It won't work. The information required to construct managed stack
>   traces is contained in runtime data structures, and it is only
>   available while the program is running. You can AOT your application,
>   then you will have more usable stack traces.

So, I did.  I AOT-compiled all of my C# DLL and EXE files.  Using the `--aot=write-symbols` option.  For a test version of my program that [crashes on purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766122/what-is-a-canonical-way-to-produce-a-segmentation-fault-in-c) so I could check if this makes the backtraces more useful.  And so far, it hasn't.  The backtrace from the main thread looks like:

```
#0  0xb7fc8402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00556df0 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00558701 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x080e59b5 in ?? ()
```

Another thread has:

```
#0  0xb7fc8402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x005f6753 in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xb6f735a7 in Mono_Unix_UnixSignal_WaitAny ()
   from /opt/novell/mono/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so
#3  0xb5416578 in ?? ()
```

And other threads seem to have been idle (in `nanosleep`, `pthread_cond_timedwait`, `pthread_cond_wait`, `sem_timedwait`, or `sem_wait`).  But the thing all backtraces have in common is that they end with that annoying `in ?? ()`, and never list any function names from "my" code.

I think this is related to some messages that `gdb` printed when it started up; for example,

```
Reading symbols from /xyz/mono/log4net.dll.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /xyz/mono/log4net.dll.so
Reading symbols from /xyz/mono/Contoso.Util.dll.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /xyz/mono/Contoso.Util.dll.so
Reading symbols from /xyz/mono/Contoso.Printing.dll.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /xyz/mono/Contoso.Printing.dll.so
Reading symbols from /xyz/mono/Contoso.LegacyDataConverter.dll.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /xyz/mono/Contoso.LegacyDataConverter.dll.so
```

Why do all the `*.dll.so` files have "no debugging symbols found"?  Do the DLLs themselves need to be built in "debug" mode or something?

And more generally, is there a way to get the managed stack trace from a Mono core dump?  (Without using `mono_pmip`, because that's only available when the process is running.)

Comment: There should be a package in your repository called "Mono Runtime - Debugging symbols" or similar. Find it, install it and then try debugging.

Comment: There's a package called `mono-addon-core-debuginfo` (for CentOS).  I assume that's it.

Comment: As a last ditch effort if you really can't fix it could you run the app under `wine`? Not an ideal solution but if you're really stuck it might work.

Comment: Did you ever have any success? I've basically reached the same point that you did and I am stuck.

Comment: theare shoud be somethink like create dump file - then if you have it and original rsp file you should be able to analyze and debug that part of error; (but I am don't try it yet)

Comment: alternative - better recreate issue and debug managed version; if it recreatable only in native one - remove from your code all parts that produce aot complile warnings

Answer (score 4):

Would it be possible to set `suspend-on-sigserv` then attach when the process crashes? I'm asssuming this is a live environment so may not be possible.

If you can do that you should be able to find the information you are after.

From the [docs](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+mono):

**MONO_DEBUG**

If set, enables some features of the runtime useful for debugging. This variable should contain a comma separated list of debugging options. Currently, the following options are supported:

...

*suspend-on-sigsegv*

This option will suspend the program when a native SIGSEGV is received. This is useful for debugging crashes which do not happen under gdb, since a live process contains more information than a core file.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about mono.. But from looking at stacktrace provided.. it show not able to get 
Symbols for mono-runtime. here is [link](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_with_GDB) which gives debugging with gdb. You need mono-runtime with symbols i.e `so` library with symbols...So you need to install [mono-runtime-dbg](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mono-runtime-dbg)...You can use tools like apt-get, yum, wget to install it.

I have unbuntu installed.. which shows following output....

```
$ apt-cache search mono-runtime-dbg
mono-runtime-dbg - Mono runtime, debugging symbols

Then
$ apt-get install mono-runtime-dbg
```

Hope you find it helpful...